# Flutter How to create a custom border that acts as a progress bar around a Container, Card, Material?

Tags: flutter

## Goal

In flutter how can I have edges around a card, container, material; that aren't fully wrapping, or aren't just one side?

Goal: To achieve a border based on the values between 0 and 1.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyWBJ.jpg

## Possible Solution 1

[Flutter | How to draw custom borders around a widget / inside a Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59551116/flutter-how-to-draw-custom-borders-around-a-widget-inside-a-container)

Create a custom border that activates sides based on progress using the border width based on percentage.

## Possible Solution 2

[how to draw a custom flutter border like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63232059/how-to-draw-a-custom-flutter-border-like-this)

[Add A Custom Decoration To Container, Using Painter Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66045318/add-a-custom-decoration-to-container-using-painter-class)

[How to create a custom border for container in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70184491/how-to-create-a-custom-border-for-container-in-flutter)

Create a custom painter. This would probably be more efficient if I also want to animate the progress bar.